# What happens if I use a 1A power supply in a router that requires 1.2A?

Tags: router

I have this d-link router, it's original power supply was 5V and 1.2A, but I found a 5V 1A supply.

It is working, but does it represent a risk to use it? What could happen?

Comment: The router might shut off without warning, or it might work fine.

Comment: The power supply voltage may drop below 5 V. It may run hot.

Comment: Back in the day, it would have been the efficient reuse of otherwise wasted equipment laying around. Everything was overbuilt as a matter of course. Today? No. Transformers are poorly wound with 30-40% regulation or worse and every penny is accounted for. It's much more risky than once. Check the temperature. If it feels like you can easily hold it after some use, that's a data point in its favor. Though it is no assurance of anything.

Comment: More chance of noise and unexpected behaviour

Comment: It will reboot during heavy traffic.

Comment: If the components aren't specified to be interoperable (and the twenty-percent power discrepancy is a mismatch) you might get unspecified behaviors.   Or not.   It's like the sell-by date on a chocolate bar; it's probably fine a week after, or a year... unless it isn't.